# Inserting several foreign keys in Fact Table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I try to assign foreign key of one table named `FactTable`. You can see how is look like table and what type of data contain.

[image]

On this table I already assign foreign key with another table named `[DIMENSION].[HS]`. For this purpose I used this line of code

```
ALTER TABLE FACT.FactTable
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (TenDigits) REFERENCES [DIMENSION].[HS](TenDigits)
```

So far so good. But problem arise when I try to connect this table with another table named `[DIMENSION].Countries`. You can see how is look like this table

[image]

Here I try to connect this two tables with code similar like code above

```
ALTER TABLE FACT.FactTable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CountryCodes) 
    REFERENCES [DIMENSION].[Countries] (CountryCodes)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 238
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__FactTable__Count__1940BAED". The conflict occurred in database "CustomsDataDW", table "DIMENSION.Countries", column 'CountryCodes'.

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem and add one more additional foreign key in to `FACT.FactTable` ?

Also here I want to mention that I can connect this table with ordinary join command with this line of code

```
SELECT *
FROM FACT.FactTable as fa
INNER JOIN [DIMENSION].Countries AS co ON co.CountryCodes=fa.CountryCodes
```

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text. Much neater and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to mention that I can connect this table with ordinary join command with this line of code

`INNER JOIN` shows only matched rows. Missing values could be identified with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fa.CountryCodes
FROM FACT.FactTable as fa
LEFT JOIN [DIMENSION].Countries AS co ON co.CountryCodes=fa.CountryCodes
WHERE co.CountyCodes IS NULL;
```

Comment: I try this and query is empty